# Kafka SSL/TLS setup

Tags: apache-kafka

I followed apache documentation for ssl setup but facing following errors.

> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject
>   alternative names present
>           at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:144)
>           at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252)
>           at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
>           at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1501)

I have a VM where I want to setup SSL and run both kafka broker and console consumer and console producer.

Please share any link which I should follow for SSL setup.

Comment: Are you using `openssl` and `keytool` in Linux to create server certificate?

Comment: yes same tool i'm using.

Comment: You have to set certificate's name as same as your hostname or IP address.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403898/x509-ssl-no-name-matching-hostname-found